# Changes to copy variable affect original

Tags: python

Here was my original code:

```
A=[[0,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0]]

rowflags=[1,0,0]
b=A

#code below changes b[0] to [1, 1, 0, 0]
for rownum in range(3):
    if rowflags[rownum]==1:
        for colnum in range(4):
            if b[rownum][colnum]==1:b[rownum][colnum]=0
            else:b[rownum][colnum]=1
print(A)
print(b)
print(b is A)
```

It gave the output:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
True
```

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) suggested changing `b=A` to `b=A.copy()` or `b=A[:]` but both yield this odd output:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
False
```

I tried a simplified example which worked fine:

```
A=[[0,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0]]

rowflags=[1,0,0]
b=A[:]

#code below changes b[0] to [1, 1, 0, 0]
b[0]=[1, 1, 0, 0]

print(A)
print(b)
print(b is A)
```

Giving the output:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
False
```

Comment: You need to use a *deep copy* here, because `.copy()` is a shallow copy. So `b = [sub.copy() for sub in A]` would work

Comment: I would use the Python Standard Library: `import copy` followed by `b = copy.deepcopy(A)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.